# building a segmented dictionary OS reports: Not a directory

Tags: kdb

I am currently trying to build a segmented partitioned splayed database.

I have a sym file and par.txt in /home/kdbUser/Downloads/dbTick/ftseStraits
I have a segmented database in /home/kdbUser/Downloads/dbTick/db/ftseStraits
The segmented database is structured as below (summary) in the ftseStraits folder:

(the CSMF.SI ric only has 2 months associated with it)

```
ftseStraits-|
            |-CSMF.SI-|
            |         |-1998.11-|
            |         |         |-(date, gmtOffset, month, price, ric, volume, .d)
            |         |
            |         |-1999.12-|
            |                   |-(date, gmtOffset, month, price, ric, volume, .d)
            |         
            |
            |-BRLL.SI-|
            |         |-1998.04-|
            |         |         |-(date, gmtOffset, month, price, ric, volume, .d)
            |         |
            |         |-1998.05-|
            |         |         |-(date, gmtOffset, month, price, ric, volume, .d)
            |         |
            |         |-1998.06-|
            |         ~         |-(date, gmtOffset, month, price, ric, volume, .d)
            ~
```

The par.txt file looks like the following (abrev. of many rics):

```
/home/kdbUser/Downloads/dbTick/db/ftseStraits/HLAA.SI
/home/kdbUser/Downloads/dbTick/db/ftseStraits/BRLL.SI
```

When I use `\l /home/kdbUser/Downloads/dbTick/ftseStraits` to load, I get the following error:

```
/home/kdbUser/Downloads/dbTick/db/ftseStraits/CSMF.SI/1999.12/.d/.d OS reports: Not a directory
```

I used `t upsert .Q.en[d;prt];` to write to disk with prt the result of a functional sql recordset to filter by month and ric appropriately and d the location of folder containing the sym and part.txt.t is the location of the folder (named as a ric) containing the splayed table.

Can you advise what I might be doing wrong?

Regards,

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each partition should have a table name / directory e.g. quote. Structured like so:

```
ftseStraits-|
            |-CSMF.SI-|
            |         |-1998.11-|
            |         |         |-quote-|
            |         |                 |-(date, gmtOffset, month, price, ric, volume, .d)
            |         |
            |         |-1999.12-|
            |                   |-quote-|
            |                           |-(date, gmtOffset, month, price, ric, volume, .d)
            |         
            |
            |-BRLL.SI-|
            |         |-1998.04-|
            |         |         |-quote-|
            |         |                 |-(date, gmtOffset, month, price, ric, volume, .d)
            |         |
            |         |-1998.05-|
            |         |         |-quote-|
            |         |                 |-(date, gmtOffset, month, price, ric, volume, .d)
            |         |
            |         |-1998.06-|
            |                   |-quote-|
            |                           |-(date, gmtOffset, month, price, ric, volume, .d)
            ~
```

This error indicates that each column file is being considered as a table dir as it is trying to look inside `.d` as if it were a table dir.

```
/home/kdbUser/Downloads/dbTick/db/ftseStraits/CSMF.SI/1999.12/.d/.d OS reports: Not a directory
```

Comment: Thanks so much Matt - this worked.
Also for anyone who follows up - to load the table you load the directory where the sym and par.txt is located.